# Function with rapidjson::Value& parameter wants an allocator when called

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I have a similar issue as an earlier question (see [Parsing object inside array in rapidjson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383852/parsing-object-inside-array-in-rapidjson) ) where I am writing a recursive function to walk an arbitrary JSON tree, and I tried the suggested answer, but my C++ compiler does not like it.

I have declared the function

```
void traverseObject(const Value& v) {
    if (v.IsObject()) {
       // . . .
    }
    else if (v.IsArray()) {
       // . . .
    }
}
```

As you suggested (for the sake of clarity, I have left out some namespace syntax that my implementation must use).  However, when calling it recursively with a Value::ConstMemberIterator itr as

```
traverseObject(itr->value);
```

or with a Value::ConstValueIterator itr as

```
traverseObject(*itr);
```

my C++ compiler generates the error

```
Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: void traverseObject(rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>,rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>> &) '
```

I admit to being new to C++ (most of my OOP experience is with Java), so I am simultaneously climbing more than one learning curve here.  Why does this function require that I call it with an allocator if I am just calling it with an object by reference?  I also looked though the RapidJSON docs and none of the examples mention the use of an allocator with method calls, so I am probably missing something basic here due to my C++ newbie-ness, but any suggestions would be helpful.

If it helps, I am using the Eclipse C++ Development Toolkit and the MinGW compiler on Windows 7.  This combination has been painful in other ways which I will not go into here, but I really like Eclipse's code analysis and refactoring tools.  I am open to using other IDEs which offer comparable features.

Thanks very much for your help.

Eric

Comment: Your code seems correct. May you post more complete code?

Comment: I think my Eclipse installation is flaky.  I installed Visual Studio 2015 with C++, and it works in that environment.  I may have to reinstall Eclipse/MinGW.  Eclipse/MinGW has other problems with RapidJSON, such as flagging line 168 of rapidjson.h: 

    #define RAPIDJSON_LITTLEENDIAN  0   //!< Little endian machine

with the error 

    "missing binary operator before token "0""

which has everyone here scratching their heads.  This happened after some time of it not having a problem, and then suddenly this error cropping up at the same time it found the error I described in this post.

Comment: I may post that as a separate question if I don't resolve the Eclispe issue soon.  At some point this has to work in an environment other than Microsoft Visual Studio.  Eclipse is my preferred IDE.